# Change enviroment variables in Windows using tools

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I am starting to learn how to use `modules` (http://modules.sourceforge.net/) on a hpc server and I like this very clean solution.

Is there any tool like `modules` for Windows OS? I am  interested in easily changing environment variables (the things I want to load don't require Windows registry).

So far I am using batch scripts which modify the environment variables, but I would like to have a centralized solution.

Comment: An interesting question. As a programmer, we have to deal with pathing issues all the time and normally specify the details for the programs before they run. This looks to be a similar setup, but having a central area would be interesting. I didn't see anything from some googles, however using something like cygwin might give you the extension you need for windows.

Comment: I don't know of an all-in-one solution like `modules`, though you could implement it pretty easily using Powershell. The standard Windows approach is just to use batch files, like you say, though (and there are limits with that approach, such as it being relatively tricky to unload the changes afterward if you want to continue using the same shell process).